# How to keep volume popup from showing when volume isn't changed?

Tags: 16.04, unity, volume-control

The volume popup shows every 20 seconds or so. Sometimes it flickers a bit. How do I disable that?

I tried to unbind the Volume Up and Volume Down keyboard shortcuts, that didn't fix it.

This problem appears on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 without any software installed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pavucontrol` I could see that the output device was flickering between "Line Out (plugged in)" and "Headphones", probably due to a loose contact (no headphone is connected). I then used `hdajackretask` to disable all output jacks except for the Line Out one by checking "Override" and selecting "Not connected". Now, in `pavucontrol` "Headphones" no longer appears in the Port selector and it no longer flickers between them.

You can install the program like this:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
```

Related answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/448138/938003