# This audio problem is driving me crazy (Kubuntu 22.04)

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, 22.04

My speakers are **disconnecting and connecting** again very frequently. They're connected via jack to the motherboard. Here's a video on the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xiDuXTZBKWA

The momment the glitch occurs, the audio source changes from
*Line Out (Built-in audio analog stereo) to
Headphones (Built-in audio analog stereo)*
causing a clipping or popping sound.

It's really annoying me because it's so, so frequent.
I've tried replacing PulseAudio with Pipewire with no results.
I've also cleaned the jack and checked the insides, I'd discard some physical problems because it was working fine on Windows before (I'm new to Linux).
I've tried disabling audio energy saving (snd_hda_intel or something like that), and a couple other solutions that I didn't understand that required adding some lines to the master config audio file.
Also, changing the output audio profile.

My motherboard model is ASUS M5AR97 EVO 2.0, idk what kind of extra info I should I give. I hope you can help me, thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solution/Workaround found. The crackling was caused by the automatic swapping between audio ports.

I installed hdajackreset. It's also on the software manager.
[How to deactivate headphones output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448104/how-to-deactivate-headphones-output)

From there you can disable whichever port you want (you can even change their functionality although it didn't work for me).

I had to virtually disable a faulty port that for some reason was making the sound swap between outputs at random times, causing the crackling sound.

You then click on "install boot overdrive", and reboot.